# Send Lat and Long details via Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to write some code that once the button is pressed it sends the lat and long coordinates via ajax to the test.php file.  The problem i am having is that it does not seem to call the test.php file.

```
<button onClick="getLocation()">Join Me</button>
                   <p id="demo"></p>
  <script>
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");

      function getLocation() {
         if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
      } else { 
          x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
          }
      }

    function redirectToPosition(position) {

     // ...
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.domain.co.uk/test.php",
        data:   "lat="+position.coords.latitude+"&long="+position.coords.longitude,

      });
   }
```

Below is the content of the test.php file,

```
$lat=(isset($_POST['lat']))?$_POST['lat']:'';
$long=(isset($_POST['long']))?$_POST['long']:'';

$to      = 'lee@recruit-technology.co.uk';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = "$lat; $long;";
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: You don't seem to have a `showPosition` function, it's called `redirectToPosition` ?

Comment: I don't get any errors, it just seems like the button isn't triggering the send

Answer (score 0):

Here. I've set up a fiddle for you. It looks like you may be referencing the wrong method name (getCurrentPosition vs redirectToPosition). If that's not the case, it looks like you never actually call redirectToPosition(), and that's why that code block never executes.

Try editing that fiddle, but changing out your actual domain URI.

```
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");

  function getLocation() {
     if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
      x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
      }
  }

function getCurrentPosition(position) {

 // ...
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://www.domain.co.uk/test.php", // -> Actual domain here.
    data:   "lat="+position.coords.latitude+"&long="+position.coords.longitude

  });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tcysvkfz/

At any rate, the method that executes your AJAX request is never invoked in your example, and that's why test.php is never hit.

Comment: OK< so i changed the domain name to the correct one, but again it's the same it doesn't seem to trigger anything

Comment: Can you save the fiddle so that I can debug it? Or set up a new one?