# Inserting HTML5 Geo Location Laititude and Longitude values into Database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

The following code gives me the latitude and longitude of the device.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>
    <button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
      var x = document.getElementById("demo");
      function getLocation() {
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        }else{
          x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
      }
      function showPosition(position) {
        x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
        "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to insert them into the database on page load but not sure how to do it.

```
$lat = ''; // Latitude value from javascript above
$long = ''; // Longitude value from javascript above

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO members(mem_lat, mem_long)VALUES(:lat, :long)");
$stmt-> bindValue(':lat', $lat);
$stmt-> bindValue(':long', $long);
$stmt-> execute();
```

I am not sure how to get the Latitude and Longitude value from the javascript to `$lat` and `$long` on page load. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can you use ajax to send lat,lng to php !

Comment: and how to get that value to ajax datastring from javascript? if it was jquery it was easy. but i have a weak hand on pure javascript.

Comment: Like here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30602538/send-lat-and-long-details-via-ajax

Comment: You can use ajax without jQuery : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: You could use php to get lat and long and not worry about the AJAX or JQuery
Check out my post to another OP here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44610720/getting-latitude-and-longitude-from-google-places-search-box/44610883#44610883

Answer (score 1):

Due to new security standards, this couldn't be executed in this snippet and should be working on a hosted page with SSL enabled (HTTPS). 
The timeout added to the function would be useful to wait for a better gps accuracy after page loading...

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Form</title>

<script>

function postAjax(url, data, success) {
 var params = typeof data == 'string' ? data : Object.keys(data).map(
   function (k) {
   return encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[k])
  }).join('&');

 var xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 xhr.open('POST', url);
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xhr.readyState > 3 && xhr.status == 200) {
   success(xhr.responseText);
  }
 };
 xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
 xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
 xhr.send(params);
 return xhr;
}
function showPosition(position) {
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
 var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
 var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
 x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
    postAjax('/gpsinsert.php', { lat: parseFloat(position.coords.latitude), lng: parseFloat(position.coords.longitude) }, function(data){ console.log(data); });
}
function errorHandler(err) {
 if (err.code == 1) {
  alert("Error: Access is denied!");
 } else if (err.code == 2) {
  alert("Error: Position is unavailable!");
 }
}
function getLocation() {
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
 if (navigator.geolocation) {

  // timeout for better GPS Accuracy !
  var options = {
   timeout: 20000
  };
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, errorHandler, options);
        
 } else {
  x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
 }
}

window.onload = getLocation()
</script>
</head>
<style>

</style>
<body>
    <p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>
    <button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. However, I modified your code to make it shorter and cleaner. Here in your code `postAjax` function was not required so I removed it. I did it using `$.ajax` method which is shorter and gives the same result.

Comment: In your first comment, you said it would be easier if it was done with Jquery!  Which was already confusing alongside the tags you used with your question. What I posted here is a plain Javascript solution :) so you changed your mind because $.ajax() that's jquery... I think the best thing to do is to post it as an answer with a header mentioning that's a Jquery solution :) That could be helpful to someone looking for both versions ;)